# login page for users in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. I have a  Login and the Register form for the user, if he is login then he will be redirected to *user_details* page. In that page he will be able to see Information. so, where I should write the query, database connection.I have a database with the table name Users.

Comment: read documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress

Comment: @prasahnt tnx bro, I want details about how we can retrive data from database, how we can insert data to database through the form, maintaining sessions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your own login/register form, if you want to make user login/register functionality from front end.

Now, then you can use inbuilt function to login authentication using "wp_signon()". and then you can redirect your form which you want to.

To fetch record, it depends on your type of data(i.e., If you use posts, then you can use follow:)

```
if(have_posts())
{ 
   while(have_posts()) : the_posts;
         echo the_title();
endwhile; 
}
```

Comment: how can I do CRUD operation in wordpress. Where I should write the query??. Can we write php code or only plugins is supported.I googled this question but I am not getting an proper answer.